# service and impl in a single osgi bundle not starting

Tags: java, osgi

I am trying to write a osgi bunlde which includes a service and serviceimpl class in two different packages.
bundle

```
- packageA
      - service class
- packageB
      - service impl class
```

Since both service and service impl are in same bundle while deploying i am getting an Missing constraint error.

**Note:** If i put both service and service impl are in different bundle it's working fine. Also if i try to import packageA from packageB it's working fine. 
Since both are in same bundle why should i import it explicitly.What is the reason behind it?

plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>manifest</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
              <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
              <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
              <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</Bundle-Version>
                <Export-Package>!${bundle.namespace}.internal.*,${bundle.namespace}.*;version="0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"</Export-Package>
                <Private-Package>${bundle.namespace}.internal.*</Private-Package>
                <_include>-osgi.bnd</_include>
                <_donotcopy>CVS|.svn|.git|.nfs*|~.nfs*|^.nfs*</_donotcopy>
                <Commit-Id>${buildNumber}</Commit-Id>
              </instructions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
          <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</Bundle-Version>
            <Export-Package>!${bundle.namespace}.internal.*,${bundle.namespace}.*;version="0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"</Export-Package>
            <Private-Package>${bundle.namespace}.internal.*</Private-Package>
            <_include>-osgi.bnd</_include>
            <_donotcopy>CVS|.svn|.git|.nfs*|~.nfs*|^.nfs*</_donotcopy>
            <Commit-Id>${buildNumber}</Commit-Id>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Here the version number is generated at runtime

Comment: What import are you talking about. The import in the java class or the import in the Manifest?

Comment: What was the error message? I mean, we could *guess* what is going wrong if you like, but that's unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @Chris -> import is in manifest.

Comment: @Neil, Missing constraint: import com.java.test.package with version 0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you import the package in the Manifest but do not export it.
Make sure you also define an Export-Package header in the Manifest.

When using the maven-bundle-plugin this should work automatically.

Comment: The problem is the package exported but in import package it is expecting the version. Both are in the same bundle how can i give a version? ie) maven bundle plugin is not taking the version of the bundle

Comment: The maven-bundle-plugin by default uses the version of the bundle unless a package version is defined. How do you configure the plugin?